# require is not defined from separate javascript file NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm sorry if the question is too basic but i'm totally new to NodeJS, and this problem has been bothering me for a while now. I already installed requireJS by typing

```
npm install requirejs
```

I used

```
express project
```

to create the project directory structure. So I have the following directory structure:

```
Webapp
    public
    routes
    views
    app.js
    package.json
```

Inside public I have the following structure:

```
public
    images
    javascripts
    stylesheets
```

I've created a javascript file in Webapp/public/javascripts/test.js and I want to require an external module which I have installed using

```
 npm install player
```

So inside test.js I wrote a single line only

```
var Player = require('../../node_modules/player');
```

and whenever I call this script and debug with the browser I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

EDIT:
I want to have a button on the client-side and when it is clicked it fires a play command that is executed on the server.

And I'm sure that this script (test.js) is being called because I created an onclick function and it goes there and I defined it in layout.jade .Back to the question, so how can I require this external library to my javascript file?

Comment: Your question seems to mix client-side JS with server-side JS and we can't really tell what you're asking about.  node.js has `require()` built-in already.  Client side files can't specify arbitrary paths on the server without creating routes to support those paths in your express server.  So, we can't really tell what scenario you're actually asking about here.  Do you understand the difference between server-side JS and client-side JS?

Comment: Are you trying to `require()` in a node.js executed JS file or in a browser executed JS file?  Where is this `var Player = require('../../node_modules/player');` located?  Is it in a server-side JS file or a JS file executed in the browser?

Comment: I think I'm mixing things a little bit, the scenario is that I want to call some function (server-side) which will have the var Player = require('../../node_modules/player'); when a button on (client-side) is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, the reason this is happening is b/c you're executing the the code in a client-side browser environment and not through Node.js.

What happens when you run `node <path to file>/test.js`?

BTW if you want to use Common.js style modules in your client code then look into Browserify or Webpack

Comment: when I execute it, it doesn't do anything and doesn't terminate and doesn't give any errors!!

Comment: Can you tell me briefly how to call a server-side function from a client-side button click for example?

Comment: @PokaYoke Without looking at your code of your it's hard to say why your module is not "doing anything". My first thought is that your module is just exporting an object or a function that you haven't invoked. Also, you're not seeing anything in the terminal because nothing is writing anything to stdout.  As far as your second comment, there are a bazillion express tutorials out there that can show you how to do that :)

Comment: thanks but the code of the module is only a single line as I wrote in the question. Thanks I'll check those too.